# MySQL Statements within Loop not executing in Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, loops, stored-procedures, transactions, database-cursor

I am writing a stored procedure which runs when a customer places an order on my website. Several statements are involved when an order is placed:

1. An entry is created in table "orders"
2. Update stock level of each product in the customer's cart(The items are listed in the
   "cart_product" table)
3. Create a new entry in table "order_details" for each product in the "cart_product" table
4. Delete the corresponding product from "cart_product" after an entry for it has been made in
   "order_details" table

When executing the stored procedure, 2,3 and 4 as mentioned above, occur within a loop "lbl" since there can be more than one product in a cart.
However, when running the stored procedure, the statements found within the loop do not seem to be getting executed: An entry is created in "orders" table, but no entries are made in "order_details" table,stockLevel is not being updated and entries in "cart_product" table are not deleted.

The transaction appears to be successful since '1' is returned after executing the stored procedure.
Here is what I have so far:

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE  sp_place_order(IN `uname` VARCHAR(15), IN `shipCost` FLOAT, IN `ndd` FLOAT)
BEGIN
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
        SELECT -1;
        ROLLBACK;
    END;

    BEGIN
        DECLARE nddBool TINYINT(1);
        DECLARE cid INT(11);
        DECLARE oid INT;

        /* CODE FOR INITIALISING CURSOR FOR LOOP*/
        DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
        DECLARE CURSOR_PRODUCT_ID INT;
        DECLARE CURSOR_QUANTITY INT;
        DECLARE CURSOR_STOCK_LVL INT;
        DECLARE CURSOR_SALE_PRICE FLOAT;

        DECLARE cursor_mycart CURSOR FOR SELECT cp.productID, cp.quantity, 
        p.stockLevel,p.unitSellingPrice
        FROM cart_product cp JOIN product p ON cp.productID = p.productID
        WHERE cartID = cid;

        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done= TRUE;

        OPEN cursor_mycart;
        /* END CURSOR CODE*/

        SELECT cartID FROM cart WHERE customer_usrname = uname INTO cid;

        IF ndd > 0 THEN
           SET nddBool= 1;
        ELSE
           SET nddBool= 0;
        END IF; 

        START TRANSACTION;

           INSERT INTO orders(customer_usrname, datePlaced, nextDayDelivery, shippingCost, 
           status,paid) 
           VALUES (uname, NOW(), nddBool, shipCost, 'pending', 0);
                        
           SELECT orderID FROM orders WHERE customer_usrname = uname   ORDER BY orderID DESC LIMIT 
           1 INTO oid;

           lbl: LOOP
               FETCH cursor_mycart INTO CURSOR_PRODUCT_ID,CURSOR_QUANTITY, CURSOR_STOCK_LVL, 
               CURSOR_SALE_PRICE;
               IF done THEN
                  LEAVE lbl;
               END IF;
               /* DECREASES STOCK LEVEL OF ITEM*/
               UPDATE product SET stockLevel = CURSOR_STOCK_LVL - CURSOR_QUANTITY WHERE productID 
               = CURSOR_PRODUCT_ID;

              /* CREATES A NEW ENTRY IN order_detail for the current product*/
              INSERT INTO order_details (orderID, productID, salePrice, quantity) VALUES 
              (oid,CURSOR_PRODUCT_ID, CURSOR_SALE_PRICE, CURSOR_QUANTITY);

             /* DELETE THE CORRESPONDING ENTRY IN cart_product TABLE, basically this empties the 
             cart*/
             DELETE FROM cart_product WHERE productID = CURSOR_PRODUCT_ID AND cartID = cid;
            END LOOP lbl;
            CLOSE cursor_mycart;

           /*DELETE FROM cart WHERE cartID = cid;*/
COMMIT;

SELECT 1;
END;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Nothing can be returned to the cursor because WHERE cartID = cid is never true - cid is not set until later when  SELECT cartID FROM cart WHERE customer_usrname = uname INTO cid; is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing can be returned to the cursor because WHERE cartID = cid is never true - cid is not set until later when SELECT cartID FROM cart WHERE customer_usrname = uname INTO cid; is executed.